# Is it safe to change files that are covered by a mount, and then bind mounted elsewhere?

Tags: filesystems, mount

I have `/dev/sdb1` mounted over `/mnt/sdb1`. I copy some files over there, say via

```
cd /root ; cp -r mydir /mnt/sdb1
```

I once unmounted `/dev/sdb1` and issued the `cp` command above - effectively copying `mydir` into a subfolder of `/mnt/sdb1` called `mydir`.

`/dev/sdb1` was then remounted and operations resumed.

EDIT: I found out that in order to check the contents of the bare directory I can do a

```
mount --bind / /elsewhere
```

and `/elsewhere/mnt/sdb1` will show me the shadowed files.

**Is it safe to manipulate them (copy, delete), in the sense that the integrity of the filesystem is preserved?**

Comment: You just answered your own question, and then asked another one.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor: I updated the question with a first finding of my own (about the ability to access the files) but the second part (about actually manipulating them) is still open. I did not want to waste people 's time with the first part but I will clarify that there was an edit.

Comment: What you have added (bind mount), was going to be my answer. There should be no problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After `mount --bind / /elsewhere`, accessing files on that filesystem through the mount point at `/` and through the mount point at `/elsewhere` is equivalent. There is no safety risk because a bind mount isn't a backdoor into a low-level mechanism, it's a door into the same room. Once you're in, it doesn't matter which door you took.